# java keystore configuration in ws:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I've configured Spring Integration `ws:outbound-gateway` with the below interceptor as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/security.html (7.3.5.1. Verifying Signatures) but I'm getting the below exception:

```
org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to invoke handler; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure,...
```

But, when I'm passing the below VM arguments without configuring the interceptor it is working fine.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:/keystore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="123456"
```

Am I missing something here? Any help on this much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And why do you still need that interceptor when everything works well without it? Please, share more info on the matter - your question isn't clear

Comment: I'm going to deploy this application in Tomcat server wherein other applications also deployed there. Moreover, in future I may need to consume another SOAP service hosted in different domain with different keystore based on its SSL certificate. In this case, I feel it is better to configure this in the interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `interceptor`, achieved this with `message-sender (org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender)` by setting the custom `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`